# Rails 3: Pass options to model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

This is my Model (Subscription) Method:

```
  def activation_codes(options = {})
    if options[:first]
      self.group.group_codes.first
    else
      self.group.group_codes
    end
  end
```

I am trying to call to this method in this fashion:

```
sub = Subscription.where(:subscription_limit => -1).first
sub.activation_codes {:first}
```

For some reason the `else`is being evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Hash` to method `activation_codes` in order to make it work as expected, like:

```
sub.activation_codes({:first => 'some value'})
```

but you're currently passing `Symbol` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That was what I was missing